# allow_none in twisted XML-RPC server

Tags: python, twisted, xml-rpc

I am building xml rpc service using twisted and I would like to use None just as it can be done in standard python lib. How can I pass allow_none to the twisted version of xmlrpc server?

**EDIT**

```
In [28]: sock = rpc.ServerProxy('http://localhost:7080',allow_none=True)

In [29]: sock
Out[29]: <ServerProxy for localhost:7080/RPC2>

In [30]: sock.list_reports()
Out[30]: ['example']

In [31]: sock.run_report('example')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fault                                     Traceback (most recent call last)

reports/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1197         return _Method(self.__send, "%s.%s" % (self.__name, name))
   1198     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1199         return self.__send(self.__name, args)
   1200 
   1201 ##


/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.pyc in __request(self, methodname, params)
   1487             self.__handler,
   1488             request,
-> 1489             verbose=self.__verbose
   1490             )
   1491 

/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.pyc in request(self, host, handler, request_body, verbose)
   1251             sock = None
   1252 
-> 1253         return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
   1254 
   1255     ##


/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.pyc in _parse_response(self, file, sock)
   1390         p.close()
   1391 
-> 1392         return u.close()
   1393 
   1394 ##


/usr/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.pyc in close(self)
    836             raise ResponseError()
    837         if self._type == "fault":
--> 838             raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
    839         return tuple(self._stack)
    840 

Fault: <Fault 8002: "Can't serialize output: cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[XMLRPC](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.xmlrpc.XMLRPC.html) accepts `allowNone` as an argument to its initializer.  So, pass `True` when instantiating your resources if you want to support `None`.

```
from twisted.web.xmlrpc import XMLRPC
resource = XMLRPC(allowNone=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be specified on client side...

when you create the proxy from your xmlrpc client - you may pass the keyword argument allow_none = True for python xmlrpclib module like below...

```
In [184]: import xmlrpclib as rpc

In [185]: sock = rpc.ServerProxy('http://localhost/xmlrpc/object',allow_none=True)
```

EDIT:

```
from twisted.web.xmlrpc import Proxy
proxy = Proxy('http://localhost/xmlrpc', allowNone=True)
```

Comment: It's not enough to define this in client.

Comment: correct, you need to specify this on server side as well.  
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("0.0.0.0", 8000), allow_none = True)